# Subclass UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So, I need to extend `UICollectionView` functionality, override Cells, etc.
In every example I see subclassing of `UICollectionViewController`, but not just `UICollectionView`.

I don't want to make my new class (called `GridSet`) as superclass for a single page (`UIViewController`) in storyboard, cause I have more elements (custom buttons, labels etc) and I don't want to maintain them in my new class, but I want to maintain them in a my page `UIViewController`.

I even want to insert two of my subclasses in one `UIViewController` and do it in storyboard (but you can't place one `UIViewController` inside another `UIViewController`.

The problem is, when I'm subclassing `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`, seems like it even don't initialize.

```
class GridSet: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let computers = [
    ["Name" : "MacBook Air", "Color" : "Silver"],
    ["Name" : "MacBook Pro", "Color" : "Silver"],
    ["Name" : "iMac", "Color" : "Silver"],
    ["Name" : "Mac Mini", "Color" : "Silver"],
    ["Name" : "Mac Pro", "Color" : "Black"]
]

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "GridSetCell", bundle: nil)
    self.registerNib(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GridSetCellDefault")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return computers.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GridSetCellDefault", forIndexPath: indexPath) as GridSetCell

    cell.label = computers[indexPath.row]["Name"]!

    return cell
}

}
```

I use nib for custom cell:

```
class GridSetCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet private weak var cLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var cBack: UIImageView!

var label: String = "" {
    didSet {
        if (label != oldValue) {
            cLabel.text = label
        }
    }
}

var back: String = "" {
    didSet {
        if (back != oldValue) {
            cBack.image = UIImage(named: back)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` and the `UICollectionViewLayout` to achieve your goals, using your versions in the system `UICollectionView`. This tutorial shows the steps:
http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial
When those are working, if you still need to subclass `UICollectionView`, you'll have working components to install "into" that new subclass.